# Unable to match string between | in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a text read from a fasta file and I am trying to read the accession number in Perl. But I am not getting an output. Here's the code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub main {

    my $file = "PXXXXX.fasta";

    if(!open(FASTA, $file)) {
        die "Could not find $file\n";
    }
    my $myLine = <FASTA>;
    my $pat = "|";
    my @Num = $myLine =~ /$pat(.*?)$pat/;
    print($Num[0]);
    close(FASTA);

}

main();
```

The content of the FASTA filehandle is:

> sp|P27455|MOMP_CHLPN Major outer membrane porin OS=Chlamydia pneumoniae OX=83558 GN=ompA PE=2 SV=1
>   MKKLLKSALLSAAFAGSVGSLQALPVGNPSDPSLLIDGTIWEGAAGDPCDPCATWCDAIS
>   LRAGFYGDYVFDRILKVDAPKTFSMGAKPTGSAAANYTTAVDRPNPAYNKHLHDAEWFTN
>   AGFIALNIWDRFDVFCTLGASNGYIRGNSTAFNLVGLFGVKGTTVNANELPNVSLSNGVV
>   ELYTDTSFSWSVGARGALWECGCATLGAEFQYAQSKPKVEELNVICNVSQFSVNKPKGYK
>   GVAFPLPTDAGVATATGTKSATINYHEWQVGASLSYRLNSLVPYIGVQWSRATFDADNIR
>   IAQPKLPTAVLNLTAWNPSLLGNATALSTTDSFSDFMQIVSCQINKFKSRKACGVTVGAT
>   LVDADKWSLTAEARLINERAAHVSGQFRF

Any clue how to fix the code to return: *P27455* ?

Comment: There are a few things you could improve in your code, such as using three-argument `open` and a lexical filehandle. Both make your code more secure. `open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!; my $line = <$fh>; ...`. You should also try to make your code more consistent. The convention is to use lower case snake case variable names, such as `$my_line` (though the _my_ in the name adds no value).

Comment: Thanks for the tips @simbabque

Comment: my ($match) = $str=~m/\|([^\|]*)\|/g;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pipe `|` holds a special meaning in regular expressions. You need to escape it. The easiest way to do that is by using `\Q` and `\E`.

```
$myLine =~ /\Q$pat\E(.*?)\Q$pat\E/;
```

Or you could use the [`quotemeta` built-in](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html).

```
my $pat = quotemeta "|";
my @Num = $myLine =~ /$pat(.*?)$pat/; # or use [^$pat]+
```

---

You can also just not use a regular expression search and simply [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) the line. If you always want the second column, this will do just as well.

```
my (undef, $num) = split /\|/, $line;
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are trying to split the line on the `|` character, so use the split function.

```
my @Num = split /\|/, $myLine;
```

This splits $myLine on `|`. Note that you may have to change the index on `@Num` to get the correct item out of it.